# Fetch data in useEffect but get Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the App.js component, I fetch data in useEffect. In URL I need a movie id I try it gets by using useParams but I could not get the id.
I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined.

```
function App() {
  const [credits, setCredits] = useState("");
  const { id } = useParams()
  useEffect(() => {
    const creditData = async () => {
      try {
        const credits = await Axios.get(
          `${baseURL}/movie/${id}/credits?api_key=${API_KEY}`
        );
        const credit = credits.data;
        setCredits(credit);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    return creditData()
  }, [id])

  return (
    < BrowserRouter >
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
        <Route path='/movie/:id/cast' render={() => <Cast credits={credits} />} />
        <Route path='/movie/:id' render={() => <MovieDetail credits={credits} />} />
      </Switch>

    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you won't get access of **id** using **useParams** because you can only use useParams in a component that is a child of your Router component, but here in your example **App** is the parent.

so basically Router component will only injects the context which is containing the match that found into the tree below and it which will be matched by the useParams hook by using the useContext hook.

Hope you get it.